# Être responsable + subordonnée

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, conjonctions, subordonnées

Je suis en train de corriger un document traduit dans lequel se trouve une phrase de ce genre (j'ai enlevé des morceaux sans importance grammaticale) :

> La personne de contact<sup>1</sup> est responsable que :
>        – Une formation soit prodiguée;
>        – Un engagement de confidentialité soit signé.

J'aimerais bien corriger cet extrait de sorte que la structure de la liste soit respectée, mais je ne vois pas bien comment raccrocher une subordonnée au mot *responsable*. Même sans l'usage du passif, la tournure *Jean est responsable de fermer la porte* ne me paraît (intuitivement) pas correcte.

Comment m'y prendre ?

---

<sup>1</sup>Qui n'est **pas** l'objet de la question :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tout comme cl-r, *la personne de contact* me gêne mais *personne qui accueille* me fait penser à la réceptionniste et je doute qu'il s'agisse d'elle.  J'ai déjà vu *référent* utilisé dans ce genre de contexte, mais le TLFi n'en donne qu'une définition linguistique.  *Responsable* est aussi une possibilité, avec une reformulation du genre

> Le responsable du stagiaire doit s'assurer
>
> - qu'une formation soit prodiguée;
> - qu'un engagement de confidentialité soit signé.

Comment: C'est la solution qui me paraît la plus naturelle.

Comment: Je me fiche pas mal des problèmes que posent (ou non) _personne de contact_, en fait :-) Mais le remplacement de _est responsable_ par _doit s'assurer_ me paraît en effet une très bonne solution.

Answer (score 4):

> La personne *qui accueille*  est
>    responsable de :
>
> - la réalisation de la formation par le client/l'étudiant/..,
> - la signature de l'engagement de confidentialité par le client/l'étudiant/.. (ou *par ce dernier)*.

Answer (score 0):

C'est consideré correct comme ça, mais sinon je mettrais le "que" dans la liste comme ça:

> La personne de contact est responsable :
>
> - qu'une formation soit prodiguée;
> - qu'un engagement de confidentialité soit signé.

Note aussi que moi j'enleverais les majuscules dans la liste...

"prodiguée" par contre... pas sûr hein! 8-) "fournie"?

Comment: Juste "donnée", ou même "suivie" vu que le sujet n'est pas précisé. Je ne suis toujours pas convaincu que "responsable que" + subordonnée soit correct, tu as des références sur ça?

Comment: Ah oui "suivie" c'est beaucoup mieux. Personellement, le que ne m'embête pas trop. Mais je suppose que tu as raison. "responsable d'assurer que ..." peut-être?

Comment: Je n'ai pas source mais de ce que je vois avec google, "responsable que" ça n'est pas utilisé...